# No libcudnn.so.6 after installing cuDNN 6.0.0 using anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed CUDA 8 and cuDNN 6 in my anaconda environment using anaconda as below:

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit==8.0 --yes
conda install -c anaconda cudnn==6.0.0 --yes
```

In the same environment, I couldn't found `libcudnn.so.6` in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64 | grep libcudnn
libcudnn.so
libcudnn.so.5
libcudnn.so.5.1.5
libcudnn_static.a
```

Is this normal? My tensorflow 1.4 is complaining `libcudnn.so.6` not found. I guess it is due to the anaconda cuDNN installation?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

The shared library you just installed with anaconda shall be located here:

```
<PATH-TO-YOUR-ANACONDA>/envs/<YOUR-ACTIVE-CONDA-ENV>/lib/
```

That said you can just add this path to you LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the linker can find the newly installed cudnn.so.6

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<PATH-TO-YOUR-ANACONDA>/envs/<YOUR-ACTIVE-CONDA-ENV>/lib/
```

Good luck!